# sharepoint 2013 unc access anonymous without credentials

Tags: networking, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2008-r2, unc

I have installed SharePoint foundation 2013 on a Windows 2008. I have successfully set the web auth to be anonymous but the problem is when i try to access with UNC path. For example I'm trying to access it from another PC in the same domain but it asks for username/password.

**Server name:** win2008server

**UNC:** \win2008server/ is the path I'm trying which requires credentials.

How can I set it up so that it won't require credentials and I can copy,paste files/folder in it?

Do I have to configure properly Windows Server 2008 R2 or it's related to it?